# Free Numpy Memory in Place

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

Is there any way to get cause numpy to release the memory used by an array? I cannot just run `del array` as the array is referenced elsewhere.

Example of why this matters and why I think this is safe:

```
def run():
   arr = np.array(....)
   arr2 = process(arr)
   fit(arr2)
```

I am able to edit `process` but not `run`. Right now `arr` is holding a lot of memory that is no longer needed after `process` runs. I would like to delete the contents from `arr` from within `process` once I have created `arr2`.

Comment: You mean deleting the `data` that is stored not only deleting the `pointer` to this data?

Comment: if the array's used elsewhere, wouldn't releasing the memory break whatever that "elsewhere" is?

Comment: Interesting question. Based on my knowledge of Python, I imagine the data will persist until all references to it are removed. But I expect some guru to show up soon and show us some numpy black magic that proves me wrong.

Comment: You might find some aid in [weakref](https://pymotw.com/2/weakref/), but as @MarcB noted, trashing stuff that you still need is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @MarcB - not necessarily. Suppose you just removed all members and now the other code will have a boring array to process.

Comment: updated with example

Comment: I tried `arr.resize(0)` but numpy caught on to that real fast with "ValueError: cannot resize an array references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function" ... which is rather nonsensical and I assume was just punishment for trying it.

Comment: In your example, `run` can just delete `arr` after it calls `process`. It isn't really any of `process`'s business whether its caller wants to keep the array, is it?

Comment: @tdelaney Got `arr.resize()` to work with `refcheck=False`.

Comment: @MikeMüller - Hmmm, I should have read the entire help message!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to resize the array to a small array:

```
arr.resize((2,), refcheck=False)
```

It changes the array in-place:

> a.resize(new_shape, refcheck=True)
>
> Change shape and size of array in-place.

...

> ### Notes
>
> This reallocates space for the data area if necessary.
>
> Only contiguous arrays (data elements consecutive in memory) can be
>   resized.
>
> The purpose of the reference count check is to make sure you
>   do not use this array as a buffer for another Python object and then
>   reallocate the memory. However, reference counts can increase in
>   other ways so if you are sure that you have not shared the memory
>   for this array with another Python object, then you may safely set
>   `refcheck` to False.